# Help to understand a proof on the existence of primitive roots modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**The theorem is as it follows:**

If $p$ is a prime number, then there is at least a primitive root modulo p.

**The proof that our teacher has taught us is the following:**

Let's suppose $p>2$.

(1) $p-1=\prod_{i=1}^{r}q_i^{n_i}$ for $q_{i}$ different primes and $n_i > 0$.

(2) ${x^{q_i}}^{n_i} - 1$ has ${q_i}^{n_i}$ roots in $\mathbb{Z}$/p$\mathbb{Z}$.

(3) ${x^{q_i}}^{n_i-1} - 1$ has ${q_i}^{n_i-1}$ roots in $\mathbb{Z}$/p$\mathbb{Z}$.

(4) There are ${q_i}^{n_i} - {q_i}^{n_i-1}$ elements $b\in$($\mathbb{Z}$/p$\mathbb{Z})^*$ that ${b^{q_i}}^{n_i}=1$ but ${b^{q_i}}^{n_i-1}\not=1$.

(5) These elements have multiplicative order ${q_i}^{n_i}$.

(6) Let $a_i$ be an element with multiplicative order ${q_i}^{n_i}$.

(7) Let a be written as: $a=\prod_{i=1}^{r}a_i$, that has multiplicative order $\prod_{i=1}^{r}q_i^{n_i}=p-1=\varphi(p)$. $\blacksquare$

I have been trying to understand the proof, but I fail at following some lines of it. First, why does he factorizes $p-1$ and not a given $p$. I know that by Fermat's little theorem we can assure (2) and (3). But I can't comprehend (4). Any help will be well-received.

Comment: becasue $\phi(p)=p-1$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is right. Primitive root modulo $p$ is related to order of $r$ modulo $p$ = $\varphi(p)$. And I believe (2) and (3) followed from Lagrange's theorem, not Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is too heavy. Set $s_i=q_i^{n_i}$ and $s_i'=q_i^{n_i-1}$.

What you want to show is that there is an element in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ with multiplicative order $s_i$. By the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ can be written as an inner direct product of subgroups
$$
(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*=H_1\times H_2\times \dots\times H_r
$$
where $H_i$ is a $q_i$-group and so $|H_i|=s_i$. Since the equation $x^{s_i'}-1$ has at most $s_i'$ roots in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, there must exist an element $a_i\in H_i$ having order $>s_i'$. Hence the order of $a_i$ is $s_i$.

(Note “has at most”, where you just say “has”.)

Now you can finish by taking $a=a_1a_2\dots a_r$ that, by standard properties of groups, has order $s_1s_2\dots s_r=p-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$4$ can be obtained from $2$ and $3$ by a simple substraction.

The cardinality of $A\setminus B$ when $B$ is a subset of $A$ is just $|A|-|B|$.

Comment: PS: I really think this proof should be done for finite fields in general, I think the proof for the specific case is obfuscated by irrelevant details.